# Why is there an input string exception for a query without where clause?

Tags: c#, mysql, linq, entity-framework, formatexception

Using ASP.NET MVC 2, Entity Framework, MySQL, VS2010 Ultimate. I have researched long but running out of clue for general Input Exception hit from my code. Although I have removed all the where clause:

```
var record = (from staff in pmsEntities.ef_staff                          
                           select staff
                           ).FirstOrDefault();
```

> [FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.]
>
> ```
> System.Number.StringToNumber(String str, NumberStyles options, NumberBuffer& number, NumberFormatInfo info, Boolean parseDecimal) +9594283    
> System.Number.ParseInt32(String s, NumberStyles style, NumberFormatInfo info) +119    
> System.String.System.IConvertible.ToInt32(IFormatProvider provider) +46    
> System.Convert.ChangeType(Object value, Type conversionType, IFormatProvider provider) +385   
> MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlDataReader.ChangeType(Object sourceValue, Type targetType) +566    
> MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 ordinal) +231    
> System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) +215    
> System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetPropertyValueWithErrorHandling(Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName) +68    
> lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +1088    
> System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly(Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet) +218    
> lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +291    
> System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Coordinator`1.ReadNextElement(Shaper shaper) +170    
> System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.SimpleEnumerator.MoveNext()  +84    
> System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault(IEnumerable`1 source) +4187840    
> System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__1(IEnumerable`1 sequence) +41    
> System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle(IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot) +59    
> System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) +150    
> System.Linq.Queryable.FirstOrDefault(IQueryable`1 source) +265    
> IDP.Models.Login.IsValid(String _username, String _pwd, Int32 _type) in C:\Users\george\Desktop\Um\idp\nur\IDP\IDP\Models\Login.cs:36
> ```

Comment: Please provide the definition of the class `ef_staff` and the result of the sql that is being called.

Comment: At first site it looks like you have a column that is a number in your model but stored as a string.  Then data in the DB for that column that cannot be converted from string to number.

Comment: You can explain what a pmsEntities.ef_staff? And in addition you can use 
`var record =  pmsEntities.ef_staff.FirstOrDefault();`

Answer (score 3):

These parts of the stack trace:

> ```
> MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlDataReader.ChangeType(Object sourceValue, Type targetType) +566    
> MySql.Data.Entity.EFMySqlDataReader.GetValue(Int32 ordinal) +231    
> System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.ErrorHandlingValueReader`1.GetValue(DbDataReader reader, Int32 ordinal) +215    
> System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.GetPropertyValueWithErrorHandling(Int32 ordinal, String propertyName, String typeName) +68    
> lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +1088    
> System.Data.Common.Internal.Materialization.Shaper.HandleEntityAppendOnly(Func`2 constructEntityDelegate, EntityKey entityKey, EntitySet entitySet) +218    
> lambda_method(Closure , Shaper ) +291
> ```

suggest that the MySQL Linq provider is having problems with some of your data - if looks like there's a field which in your **object model** is defined as an `int`, but the corresponding **data in the database** isn't represented as an integer.

Without knowing more about your database and how you set up your Entity Framework model, I couldn't say exactly what the problem is.

Comment: You really enlighten me, I have changed the type in object model and refresh the mapping, issue solved! I am first day in c# and didn't realise the mapping, stupid me.